# Microsoft Owin Self Host crashes with Google Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, owin, self-hosting

I'm trying to self-host some static files on my C# app using Microsoft Owin.
It works perfectly well in both IE (for once...) and Firefox, but Chrome doesn't, it's like it's not even trying to connect (I can't see any traffic in Chrome's dev tools).

The problem, of course, is I specifically need it to work on Chrome.

Owin seems a mature project, and I can't believe I'm the only one having this problem, yet I can't find anyone else having the same so I must do something wrong.

This is the code:

```
const string url = "http://localhost:6667/";

var fileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(webSiteFolder.FullName);

var options = new FileServerOptions
{
    EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true,
    FileSystem = fileSystem,
};

_server = WebApp.Start(url, builder =>
{
    builder.UseFileServer(options);
});

Console.WriteLine("Listening at " + url);
```

Any clue?

Thanks!

Comment: it's because these ports are considered as unsafe by Chrome, see http://superuser.com/questions/188058/which-ports-are-considered-unsafe-on-chrome

Comment: I learned something today! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use another port, for example 5000

Comment: This is crazy, I tried your suggestion just for the sake of it (what's the difference between 6667 and 5000 ??), and it worked...
Before that, I did tried other ports (6664, 6665), to no avail.
Why is it working with 5000????